# Laravel backpack 6 pro wysiwyg field doesn't works

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg, laravel-10

I'm trying to change a field in my CRUD controller from text to wysiwyg, but it doesn't work, i have this:

```
CRUD::field([
        'name' => 'instrucciones',
        'type' => 'wysiwyg',
        'label' => 'Instrucciones',
        ]);
```

there is no error on console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzLxQ.png)

I'd tried with ckeditor and summernote types, but doesn't work either